# C++ non-iterator based range library?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, iterator, range

I've been frustrated by the unhandiness of stl iterators and am looking for something more usable.  In particular, a concept that is easier to map and filter, and one that is easier to implement too: basically C#/python/ruby/everything-but-C++ style enumerations.

I came across Andrei Alexandrescu's **[Iterator's must go!](http://blip.tv/file/2432106)** boostcon keynote of 2009 in which he describes a range concept that pretty much is exactly what I'm looking for and much more.

Does anybody know if something like this was actually implemented?  I know of boost::range, but that's not an ideal solution; it's implemented in terms of iterators (which is more confusing and complex, less efficient, less general, and makes writing your own one at least as messy as implementing an iterator).  Still, it's better than nothing.  Is there anything better out there?

***Edit:*** there's been lot's of discussion as to why this is at all attractive.  **[On iteration](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1407357)** explains the motivation more clearly.  I realize the link to D - but that shouldn't distract from the argument itself.

Comment: I've been searching for a replacement to stl iterators too. They are so ugly without proper auto, foreach and lambda. But I guess that a template-based range would lead to the same kind of problems...

Comment: I suggest you to be more skeptical about Andrei's presentation, he has his own motives. I agree that he makes some good points, but Stepanov had his good points too. Ranges are not always intuitive. Most of your claims regarding boost ranges are unbased. Also remember that you cannot model your complex world much simpler than it is.

Comment: @ybungalobill: perhaps, but I'm fed up enough with iterators to give something else a shot. And boost::range really isn't quite it (I don't know what you mean with unbased): it requires you to implement iterators and thus maintain code for *both* iterators *and* ranges - and I'm looking for something simpler, not more complex. Finally, the fact that so many other languages have succeeded using range-like concepts is a good hint that this isn't some far-out there impractical concept. I'm looking for C++ enumerators (not iterators), and andrei presented something even better: what's not to like?

Comment: Btw, I don't want to turn this into a stepanov vs. andrei issue; iterators made sense coming from a C background but it's 2 decades later; lamba's are coming and functional programming idioms and techniques mean that iterators' inflexibility hurts.  For me, it's time to at least *try* something else.

Comment: @Eamon, why would ranges be simpler than iterators? Even if you don't implement them as 2 iterators they are still basically 2 const iterators. They could be more convenient to *use* in certain cases, but is there a reason why their non-iterator *implementation* would be simpler than an iterator-based one?

Comment: I don't agree with you all: iterators *are* flexible.

Comment: @Alexandre C: Iterators inflexibility isn't fundamental; it's a consequence of the impracticality of actually defining new iterators or iterator transforms: it's rarely worth it, so *in practice* in most cases you stick with what the library has to offer.  (Compare with python's generators, for instance).

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne: iterator transforms (filtering, composing with a function, taking member pointers to the result...) and  "special" output iterators (which forget all but last of what you give to them, or store a modified/filtered version) are *precisely* what makes them flexible. What is *not* flexible is the iterator classes of the standard: ie. no way to distinguish between rvalue/lvalue iterators. I found a C++0x proposal to address this issue though. With auto and lambda, they are a great tool to enhance C++ with runtime efficient expressive functional constructs.

Comment: @7vies: generators aka ranges are *not* "basically 2 const iterators".  The "end" iterator doesn't necessarily exist in *most* cases: think of a 0 terminated string, a lazy fast-row-first search algo, a (lazy) regex implementation (returning all matches), a network stream, UI interaction events, etc.  Sure, you could implement some kind of "special" iterator value (but that's not always trivial nor overhead-free), but an explicit end condition is much simpler all around.

Comment: @Alexandre C.: see for instance http://www.boostpro.com/about/vision/expressiveness/.  I realize I *can* express all kinds of things with iterators, but it's not the *obvious* way to do so.  The fact that I need *two* is bad, as is the fact that the *end* iterator is an actual value of the same type in the first place.  So, in principle they're flexible, but it practice that flexibility is unhandy enough so as to be not worth it in almost all cases.

Comment: This is obviously a sensitive topic for many: perhaps another CW question on the merits of iterators would be a better place to discuss that.  As the OP, please just believe me when I say I'd appreciate an alternative to iterators.

Comment: @Eamon: I think I see what you mean. Indeed, when you write a `iterator_pair` which is constructed with 2 iterators, and dereferences as a pair of rvalues, the `operator!=` is designed with termination criterion in mind, and not with inequality semantics. And it is very difficult to get the other comparison operators right (should i < j always be equivalent to !(i >= j) ?). One solution in some cases is to use the default constructor of an iterator to indicate end of stream, like `stream_iterator` does. I agree, this does sometimes lack flexibility.

Comment: @Eamon: You are right, I had a too narrow example in my head. But even assuming an abstract "explicit end condition" as you said, you would still need at least one iterator, bringing me back to my question again - how could a range implementation be simpler than iterators if it is based on them? Or do you see another way of implementing a range, without iterators at all?

Comment: @7vies: yeah, you'll need some kind of "goto next value or detect end" function and something to extract the current value at the very least.  But you don't need to implement comparison semantics, you don't need to implement some kind of sentinel value nor worry about what happens if you increment *that* (UB?)... it's just removing friction for a process that's conceptually simple but practically tricky in C++ right now.  See [On iteration](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1407357) about how C++ might do this, or look at .NET's IEnumerable to see how others do it.

Comment: @Eamon: Try boost::iterator_facade, they let you to implement the bare minimum you need to get an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a few years, but it looks like there's a library out there that implements proper functional style sequences now: [**C++ Streams**](http://jscheiny.github.io/Streams/).

Code sample from the project's homepage:

Summing the first 10 squares:

```
int total = stream::MakeStream::counter(1)
    .map([] (int x) { return x * x; })
    .limit(10)
    .sum();
```

Comment: Although ranges like in D also forward random access and the other traits where possible, which guarantees better performance in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

Seems pretty easy to do yourself -- assuming you don't mind a bit of work/typing

I haven't compiled this yet but something like this should move you a bit along

```
template< typename T>
class enumeration : boost::noncopyable {
virtual T& next() = 0;
virtual bool has_next() = 0;
};

template< typename T>
class editable_enumeration : public enumeration<T> {
virtual void remove() = 0;
}

//That was simple enough, now for adapting the std containers we
//will use the iterator interface already exposed. For new classes,
//we can implement iterators in any way we want. (e.g. copy python or java)

template < class C >
class const_std_enumeration : public enumeration<C::value_type>
{
protected:
C::const_iterator iter_;
C::const_iterator end_;

public:
typedef C::value_type value_type;

const_std_enumeration( C const& c) :
iter_(c.begin()), end_(c.end()) { } //c++0x use std::begin(c), std::end(c) instead

virtual value_type& next() { if(iter_!=end_) return *iter_++; throw std::runtime_error("No more elements"); }
virtual bool has_next() { return iter_!=end_; }
};

template < class C>
class std_enumeration : public enumeration<C::value_type>
{
protected:
C& c_;
C::iterator iter_;
C::iterator end_;

public:
typedef C::value_type value_type;

std_enumeration( C& c) :
c_(c), iter_(vector.begin()), end_(vector.end()) { }

virtual value_type& next() { if(v_!=end_) return *iter_++; throw std::runtime_error("No more elements"); }
virtual bool has_next() { return iter_!=end_; }
virtual remove() { iter_ = c_.erase(iter_); }
};


//Since we can't add methods to std containers, we will use an
//overloaded free-function `enumeration` to get enumerations from ANY container
//We could use `auto_ptr` or `unique_ptr`, but for simplicity's sake, I'm
//just using raw pointers

template < class C >
editable_enumeration<C::value_type>* enumeration( C&c ) { return new std_enumeration<C>(c); }

template < class C >
enumeration<C::value_type>* enumeration( C const& c ) { return new const_std_enumeration<C>(c); }
```

for all other containers, merely ensure that `enumeration` is defined and returns either an enumeration or editable_enumeration. If you other container already implements the  iterator interface, then this should work

We can now write:

```
template<typename T>
bool contains( enumeration<T>* e, T const& t) {
while(e->has_next())
  if ( t == e->next() )
    return true;
return false;
}
...
std::vector<int> v = getIntVector();
if( contains( enumeration(v), 10 ) ) std::cout<<"Enumeration contains 10\n";
std::list<int> l = getIntList();
if( contains( enumeration(l), 10 ) ) std::cout<<"Enumeration contains 10\n";
```

It should be noted one huge advantage the iterator concept holds over this is the case where the next element is requested when then `has_next()` would return false. For iterators, end()++ is (IIRC) undefined behavior. For teh enumeration, it is defined to `throw std::runtime_error(...)` which may be worse for some people.

Comment: undefined behavior is not better than an exception: it's *possibly* an exception; or maybe an exception (or access violation) much later at nondeterministic time.

Comment: thanks for the implementation!  This isn't what I'm looking for, however; such an undertaking would need to be part of a larger, tested, library.  After all, large parts of `algorithm` need to be reimplemented, and high performance is not a given (in particularly, you're using virtual dispatch here).

Comment: Why are you returning enumerators by pointer instead of by value?  That opens the door to memory leaks and unexpected behavior (`contains` isn't a read-only check, it modifies the range?  highly counterintuitive!)

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne The reason I use virtual dispatch is to decouple the types (`enumeration`, `editable_enumeration`) from the containers they iterate over: Using OO design instead of generic algorithm design. IMO, if you want the high-efficiency, use iterators.

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne As for rewriting algorithms, you don't. Create an enumeration_iterator (forward iterator). When an iterator is incremented passed the end of the enumeration (or `end()` is called), the iterator doesn't call next(), it noops. All iterators with has_next()==false are `==`. Add a copy constructor and this allows all forward_iterator required algorithms to work. See `istream_iterator` for an example of how to implement this.

Comment: @Ben Voigt. I wanted to decouple the type of the enumeration from the type of container. This necessitated using virtual functions (so all `editable_enumeration<int>` are the same regardless of weather or not they are enumeration over a vector, list, whatever. Since I am now ALWAYS returning a subclass, I must return by pointer or I will slice my class.

Comment: Ahh, that's wise.  On the other hand indirect calls are a bit of a steep price to pay, there's a reason C++ algorithms use templates to accept different iterator types instead of dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: @Ben Voigt. We could do everything with generic techniques (templated functions) but then we're just implementing forward-iterators with different syntax. Look at the `istream` library. They use virtual functions for the same reason I do, so a function that needs a character stream doesn't have to care about what underlying thing holds the data. istreams are pretty much awkwardly worded enumerations<char|wchar>. You can call next on them (`get`), you can call has_next `eof` (nothing says that `has_next()` can't block either)

Comment: @Eamon Nerbonne About your first comment: UB is horrid. BUT sometimes when the standard says UB it turns out to just be compiler specific behavior. Also, sometimes people have exceptions disabled. In that case having the throw just won't work right. Remember that the UB in question only really happens when dereferencing the out-of-bounds iterator. The exception happens immediately.

Comment: Incrementing an end pointer is a bug.  An exception is OK, UB is less pretty but also OK - but even if you have exceptions disabled, a throw is not impossible: it just means program termination (unless you've disabled exceptions yet have a catch block - evil).

Comment: @KitsuneYMG templated ranges are similar but meaningfully different from forward iterators.  Read the "On iteration" link; but in particular, it's easier to implement (fewer operations), easier to transform (fewer operations, only 1 object to worry about), and easier to consume (only one object to track).  It's not *quite* as powerful; but it's also more general, and in practice even plain slist semantics are fine for 80% - ranges look fine for pretty much everything.

Comment: @Kitsune: I like your iterator-wrapper idea :-).  You'd still want to reimplement the functions, even if it's just in terms of STL using the wrapper to clean up the api and tweak the semantics of a few functions to be more range-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

May be this one will help you: http://rangelib.synesis.com.au/ .